# How do you get glassfish to show debug information for JSPs?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm switching from Tomcat to Glassfish for an app server. Glassfish is so much more complicated its a little overwhelming. Anyway now I'm getting an exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.jsps.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java from :67)

Where tomcat shows you the line number and gives me some information on the stderr or stdout, this just shows the error in the compliled jsp file, which is pretty much useless to me. How can I get it to show more information - at least the line in the JSP throwing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Log in Administration Console and go to Configuration -> your configuration -> Logger settings ->Log levels. Set you log levels to Finest or whatever.

Regards